# (Lenovo Thinkpad + ubuntu19.04) Touch pad not working

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 19.04

Lenovo Thinkpad T440 + ubuntu 19.04

I update my laptop from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04, When I turn on at that time touchpad was working fine but, When I slide down the screen (Basically after sleep mode) and open It again, Then touchpad was stopped working, Also little red Eraserhead (Red Joystick) is stopped working, (No cursor move when I move red joystick) after that  I need to restart my PC, no other option.

A pointer is working fine if any external mouse is attached.

Comment: @K7AAY I edited the question, It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two commands to fixed that, when stop work, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal, and type:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

but I don't know how to automate this, if you find me let me know :)

Comment: you can create a script to simplify the launch : 1) create the script file and save these 2 commands (`sudo` command won't be needed) 2) use `chmod +x script.sh` to make your script executable 3) each time you need to use these command, launch your script using `sudo ./script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

To automate the commands, as mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1191817/356228) create this shell script:

**Open terminal and run:**

```
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/post-suspend.sh
```

**Copy/Paste the code below:**

```
#!/bin/bash/

if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
# nothing goes here

elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
sudo modprobe psmouse
fi
```

**Update script permission:**

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/post-suspend.sh
```

**NOTE:**

- For me **sudo modprobe psmouse** worked. If this doesn't work for you, then try with **sudo rmmod psmouse**
- **Debian users** should replace all instances of **usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep** with  **/lib/systemd/system-sleep/**

Ref: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/run-scripts-and-commands-on-suspend-and-resume-on-linux/

Comment: Why do you need the empty "pre" if case? I think you could easily skip it