# How does suspend fix my touchpad and break my wifi, and how can I take control over this?

Tags: kernel, xubuntu, suspend, systemd, thinkpad

So I’ve got a Thinkpad A475 running xubuntu 22.04. Everything works great right from the start, except the touchpad and the little red nob. Now if I suspend the laptop, the touchpad and the little nob will work perfectly until reboot. Then I have to suspend to have them working again.

The real problem though, is that when I suspend/resume and the touchpad is working. Wifi is suddenly struggling with lots of packet loss. Ssh into the laptop from LAN is very laggy. Ping to and from the laptop shows a few >5ms pongs and a few <300ms.

When the machine is suspended some kernel modules are removed and then added at resume, and I suspect this is where the problem lies. But could someone help me debug this? As in where do I find the configuration for the suspend behavior? How can I see what kernel modules are unloded/loaded?

Comment: From [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182872/lenovo-thinkpad-ubuntu19-04-touch-pad-not-working) it does seem I’ve got a fix for the touchpad. But the wifi is a bit more tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, that I just had to update the firmware of my thinkpad. :facepalm:. All problems are suddenly gone.

So if someone comes looking for this, I got the Bios upgrade ISO from [lenovo.com](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-A-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-A475-TYPE-20KL-20KM/downloads/DS500949)

Installed gen iso image:

```
sudo apt-get install genisoimage
geteltorito bios-update.img the_bios_iso.iso
```

Flashed to a usb stick using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), boot from the usb stick and follow the instructions.